# Windows 7 Libraries and Windows Home Server

Tags: windows-7, windows-home-server, windows

So I'm currently running the Windows 7 Release Candidate, and I have a fairly new Windows Home Server machine. I'm trying to add the "Video" share to the Video Library. First try gives me an error indicating that it needs to be indexed to be added.

So I install Windows Search 4.0 on the WHS machine. Unfortunately that also failed to work, even though the shares are being indexed by Windows Search on the WHS machine. Any ideas as to what is necessary?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about pre-release s/w.


Answer (score 1, accepted):

The now-in-beta, soon-to-be-released WHS Power Pack 3 includes direct support for the Windows 7 features. Read more at the [team's blog](http://blogs.technet.com/homeserver/archive/2009/07/17/windows-home-server-power-pack-3-beta-includes-enhancements-for-windows-7-based-computers.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You first need to add the Video share to the indexing service on Windows 7 RC. The library indexes everything in it by default. Although there is an index on the WHS server, Windows 7 won't make use of it. The use of indexing on servers only work with Windows 2008 Servers and higher. Even with Desktop Search 4.0 this is still not accessible by Vista/Windows 7 machines.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Windows 7 RC when trying to add a generic share hosted on Linux to my libraries, but I have since uninstalled Windows 7.

From what I understand, WHS shares are fully indexed, and your additional work of installing desktop search should definitely ensure that (even though they already were).

Is the share empty?  Maybe it is not indexed because there is nothing in it yet?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to add a second answer to ensure that this is seen. I happened to try the same thing today using Windows Server 2003 and ended up reading the help in Windows 7. Something usefull we always ignore because google is so much quicker.

To add a location to the library it needs to be indexed. According to the help if the file is on a network location already indexed, it should be added without a hassle, however it does not define what would make the location appear as indexed.

The alternative method is to make the folder available offline. This can be done by right-clicking on the folder and then selecting Always available offline. The drawback is that the files will be stored on the local computer.

The latter defeats the object.

If your running 32Bit Vista or Windows XP and Win 7 you can install [this](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=f7e981d9-5a3b-4872-a07e-220761e27283&displaylang=en&Hash=JTm30aLPjk8x6t3Iwvuw5fB4oT4UZwCHlFCp91/n8tt/boVeoV5DX44yzu8Kc0nwblWBgezWUaA/rnMU9FWNYg%3d%3d) add-in which allow the indexer to index network and UNC locations, however it is not available for 64Bit.

Another option according to [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/network-internet/4616-indexing-network-share-locations.html) forum post is to create a symbolic link to the network share.

Comment: I'm running 64 bit win7. Creating a symbolic link seems somewhat hackish, though if that's the only way to go...

Comment: I tested it and it does work. I have sent a query to the Windows 7 team regarding this and will hopefully get a response soon.